# How I can add more columns to show in my relationships in adonis using node.js?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have this model:

**Book:**

```
class BookSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('books', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('description')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }
```

**BookUnit:**

```
class BookUnitSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('book_unit', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('book_id').references('id').inTable('books').notNullable()
      table.integer('unit').notNullable()
      table.string('description')
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.timestamps()
      table.unique(['unit', 'sequence', 'book_id'])
    })
  }
```

**BookUnitQuestion**

```
class BookUnitQuestionSchema extends Schema {
      up () {
        this.create('book_unit_question', (table) => {
          table.increments()
          table.integer('book_unit_id').references('id').inTable('book_unit')
          table.string('question_form')
          table.string('option_form')
          table.string('type_answer')
          table.string('description')
          table.string('correct_answer_description')
          table.integer('correct_answer_description_id')
          table.text('image_sound')
          table.boolean('status').defaultTo(false)
          table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
          table.timestamps()
        })
      }
```

I need to make a query that me returns all the questions of one determined book. I try this way:

```
const Book = use('App/Models/Book')

const book = await Book.find(2) //Get book from id
await book.load('book_unit_questions') // Load book_unit_questions
const questions = book.getRelated('book_unit_questions') // Return questions
return questions
```

So, I have this json:

```
[ {"id":1,"book_unit_id":2,"description":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
     {"id":2,"book_unit_id":5,"description":454,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
]
```

I need to put more book_unit informations inside this json, like `book_unit.description`, `book_unit.sequence`"...
Porém, eu preciso de mais informações sobre o book_unit_id, como por exemplo, o description dele.

In my query I return book_unit_id but I need to add this others columns of bookunit, how I can do this?

**My book models:**

```
user () {
    return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
        .select('id', 'username')
}

book_units(){
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/BookUnit')
}

book_unit_questions() {
    return this.manyThrough('App/Models/BookUnit', 'book_unit_questions')
}
```

**BookUnit Models:**

```
book_unit_questions() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/BookUnitQuestion')
}

book () {
    return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Book')
}

user () {
    return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
        .select('id', 'username')
}
```

**bookUnit Question model**:

```
static get table () { return 'book_unit_question' }

user () {
    return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
        .select('id', 'username')
}

book_units(){
    return this.belongsTo('App/Models/BookUnitQuestion')
}

books () {
    return this.manyThrough('App/Models/Book', 'book_unit_questions', 'id', 'book_unit_id')
}
```

Comment: Hi, you want something like that : https://ibb.co/bFCH6cG

Comment: @CrBast hi, i need something like this: {id: 1, book_unit_id: 2, question_form: "Texto", option_form: "Texto", type_answer: "Aberta", book_unit: {id:2, description: BOOK_2_FORSTUDENTES, unit:2}